# Create Django Objects outside of Admin

Tags: python, django, class, object

I'm new to django and while the admin site is useful I need to be able to do simple functions without it. I would like to automatically manage my objects.

Is it possible to create objects outside of the admin site?

I know one way to do it

```
Class Foo (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def create(cls, name, url):
        bar = cls(name=name)
        return bar


s1 = Foo.create("THIS IS A NAME")
s1.save()
```

But I'm having trouble adding new variable to the object
How do I add unique variables to each object

thanks

Comment: Why do you believe that adding arbitrary attributes is a good thing?

Comment: I working on a web app that creates new livestream pages and I need each one to be unique. I'm using api from third party website to populate the livestream information

Comment: So then why not create a model that contains the fields you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I am not sure about your question. If you want to have a `unique` field for your model you can do

```
yourUniqueFieldName = models.TextField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

And this for a pair of (or more) unique fields you can do

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ('field1', 'field2',)
```

Official documents is always your best friend as a start:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/